# For loop in R to automate mean calculations of Dataframes

Tags: r, function, for-loop

The following code for calculating the column mean values of dataframes works:

```
res <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  z <- df[i,]
  z <- unlist(z) 
  z <- mean(z)
  res[[i]] <- z
  print(res)
```

However if I try to convert the code into a function, the output list is stating "NULL" for each column, except the last one:

```
res <- list()
col.mean <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    z <- x[i,]
    z <- unlist(z) 
    z <- mean(z)
    res[[i]] <- z
    return(res)
}
```

The following function seems to be working, however I do not understand the logic behind it. For me both functions are similar, except the latter one is more simplyfied.

```
res <- list()
col.mean <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    res[[i]] <- mean(unlist(x[i,]))
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean means of rows, then use `rowMeans()` instead. For columns use `colMeans()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to calculate means of rows.

**1.** A function, which is rapid, exists in `base R`: `rowMeans()`. See `help(rowMeans)` for further information.

**2.** For-loops are not a very `R`-like way of doing things.
Some modifications to your loop:

```
# do not grow objects inside loops! 
res <- vector("list", nrow(data))
# I prefer seq(nrow(data) over 1:nrow(data)
for(i in seq(nrow(data))) {
  res[[i]] <- mean(unlist(data[i, ]))
}
```

Wrapped into a self-written function:

```
rowMeans2 <- \(df, ...) {
  res <- vector("list", nrow(df))
  for(i in seq(nrow(df))) {
    res[[i]] <- mean(unlist(df[i, ]), ...)
  }
  res
}
```

The "`...`-*parameter/argument*" allows you to specify arguments in `mean()` such as `na.rm = TRUE`.

**3.** In `R`, we often use `*apply()`-functions (wrappers around loops) instead of of self-written loops. Here I used `lapply()` as it seems you want your result to be stored in list format.

```
rowMeans3 <- \(df, ...) {
  lapply(X = seq(nrow(df)), FUN = \(i) mean(unlist(df[i, ]), ...))
}
```

**4.** An alternative avoiding `unlist()` as suggested by @Jilber Urbina in a comment below:

```
rowMeans4 <- \(df, ...) {
  sapply(X = seq(nrow(df)), FUN = \(i) mean(as.numeric(df[i, ]), ...))
}
```

Tested on an in-build data set called "iris". I removed non-numeric columns. Data:

```
data <- iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)]
```

Comment: You can use `sapply` instead of `lapply` and avoid using `unlist`

Comment: Thank you. I know. `unlist(mean(...))` is what the questioner uses.

Comment: I see a challenge with these approaches like none of them remove the character column. lets take the example of the `iris` dataframe for the first row if we take the example `sapply(1, \(x){ mean(unlist(iris[x,])) })` the results is 2.24, however if we actually consider the numeric columns only the result should be 2.55. The correct code would be ` iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)]` which you mentioned, but the other code seems not right

Comment: Combining data of different types, in the given example numeric and factor, appears pointless and dangerous to me. Notice that, for the first row,  your approach coerces "setosa" (a factor level) to "1". The row mean is influenced.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works for me with few changes as below

```r
res <- list()

col.mean <- function(x){
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  z <- x[i,]
z <- unlist(z) 
z <- mean(z)
res[[i]] <- z
return(res)
}
}

col.mean(iris)

print(res)
```